# Are all the dependencies available in this tiny compiler written in python to get this to work

Tags: python

https://github.com/AZHenley/teenytinycompiler.git

Can you get this to run I got it from this website:

[http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~azh/blog/teenytinycompiler1.html](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/%7Eazh/blog/teenytinycompiler1.html)

I followed this tutorial and it failed to load the source file.

I am new to python.

**this is a screenshot of when I ran the python project**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Please do not share images. Instead, please post your code as clear text. Include the error messages, and expected output.

Comment: You need to pass an argument to your program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass in the source file. The command you have now only starts the TeenyTiny compiler. You can pass in the source file as follows.

```
"C:/Users/Ackeem/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "C:/Users/Ackeem/Desktop/teenyTIny Compiler/teenytinycompiler/part2/teenytiny.py" "C:/Users/Ackeem/Desktop/teenyTIny Compiler/teenytinycompiler/part2/hello.tiny"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code did run but there were no parameters passed to it.
sys.argv is the object that holds parameters being passed.